# jQuery - append(item) to closest class

Tags: jquery, ajax

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function(){
    var form = $('.formet');
    var submit = $('#knappUp');

    form.on('submit', function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();

$.ajax({
  url: 'ajax_post_com.php',
  type: 'POST',
  cache: false,
  data: $(this).serialize(),           //$(this) = a form
  beforeSend: function(){
      submit.val('Submitting...').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
  },
  success: function(data){
    var item = $(data).hide().fadeIn(800);
    form.parent().nextAll('.note-block:first').append(item); 
    //GOAL: append(item) onto the .note-block after only (this) form
  },

},
    error: function(e){
    alert(e);
    }
  });
 });
});         
</script>
```

The page holds a loop with multiple `<form>`´s followed by the `<div class="note-block">`.
What i want is to tell my jQuery to `.append(item)` to the next (closest) `.note-block` it finds.

(Today the last data posted in the form is being displayed on all .note-block, until the page is being refreshed - but i don´t want to refresh the page - obviously)

It's probably very simple - but i got 100% stuck here in my brain freeze.

Please help

--UPDATE--

The page loop...

```
echo "<div class='notat' id='typenote".$clients_id."'>
        <form class='formet' method='post'>
            <textarea name='note' id='note' placeholder='Legg til notat'></textarea>
            <input type='text' name='client_id' id='client_id' value='".$clients_id."' style='display:none;' />
            <input type='text' name='user' id='user' value='".$class->getCurrentUser('users_fullname')."' style='display:none;'/>
            <input type='submit' value='SAVE' id='Up'/>
            <input type='button' class='page-fade' value='CANCEL' id='Down'/>
        </form>
    </div>";
?>
<div style="clear:both; height:2px;"></div>

<?php
    $note_query = mysql_query(
    "SELECT * FROM ... WHERE client_id = $clients_id ORDER BY note_id DESC");
?>

<div class="note-block"></div>
    <?php while($nota = mysql_fetch_array($note_query)): ?>

    <div class="note_post"> 
        <strong><img src='img/user.png' width='15px'> <?php echo $nota['user']?></strong> 
        <?php echo strftime('%e', strtotime($nota['note_created']));?>. 
        <?php echo strftime('%b', strtotime($nota['note_created']));?>. 
        <?php echo strftime('%y', strtotime($nota['note_created']));?> (<?php echo date('H:i',strtotime($nota['note_created']))?>)
        <br>
        <p><?php echo $nota['note']?></p>
    </div>
<?php end while?>
```

--UPDATE--

The data/ item from `url: 'ajax_post_com.php'`

```
<div class="note_post">
  <img src='img/user.png' width='7.5px'> <?php echo $user?>
  <?php echo date("j. M. Y");?> (kl. <?php echo date("H:i");?>)
  <p><?php echo $note?></p>
</div>
```

Comment: can you post a small snippet of the HTML?

Comment: ok - se above. Thanks for "heeling"

Comment: it is unlikely that in the success handler `$(this)` still refers to the form being submitted. Are you calling `$.ajax` in the context of another function?

Comment: No, only this function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the HTML you provided, it looks like `.note-block`'s are siblings of the form's **parent**. So try:

```
$(this).parent().nextAll('.note-block').append(item);
```

**EDIT (again - based on OP's new code)**

At the time the ajax `success` handler is called, `$(this)` likely does not refer to the original form element. You could save a reference to the form (being submitted) in the submit handler, to use within the `$.ajax` call:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var allForms = $('.formet');
    var submit = $('#knappUp');

    allForms.on('submit', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        //form variable created inside submit handler
        var thisForm = $(this);
        $.ajax({
            url: 'ajax_post_com.php',
            type: 'POST',
            cache: false,
            //use the form variable
            data: thisForm.serialize(),
            beforeSend: function(){
                submit.val('Submitting...').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
            },
            success: function(data){
                var item = $(data).hide().fadeIn(800);
                //use the form variable
                thisForm.parent().nextAll('.note-block:first').append(item);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

You could even save a reference to the target `.note-block` you want to update:

```
allForms.on('submit', function(e) {
    var thisForm = $(this);
    var noteBlock = thisForm.parent().nextAll('.note-block:first');
    //try console.log(noteBlock); right here to see what it is
    $.ajax({
        ...
        success: function(data){
            var item = $(data).hide().fadeIn(800);
            //use the noteBlock variable
            noteBlock.append(item);
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: ok...are you sure `$(this)` is your form element? Can you log to console and verify?

Comment: From original post: "data: $(this).serialize()," Thats works. Grabs the input data from the form - all data is being sent successfully to table

Comment: Yes, see my additional comment to your original post. `$(this)` probably does not refer to the form at the time the `success` handler is called.

Comment: so, what would you suggest instead? any ideas?

Comment: Ok! sounds right. But there is something missing... tried it and the post is being submitted to all class=note-block. Also tried with .next() - same result

Comment: ah, right. use the additional `:first` selector to get the first `.note-block`

Comment: Didn´t work =( - updated original post with full script now. And also the data from 'url: 'ajax_post_com.php'

Comment: as you've written it, `var form = $('.formet');` will select all forms with a class of `formet`. See my updates...

Comment: Brilliant! Thanks a lot for your patient and time spent!

Comment: I sure did!! Can i please ask you for one last thing? If you would clear the <textarea name='note' id='note' placeholder='Legg til notat'></textarea> on success (data sent) - what would you do?

Comment: ... sometimes it good to think for your self ;) thisForm.trigger('reset'); submit.removeAttr('disabled'); - Again, learned a lot! Thank you

Answer (score 0):

```
$(this).next('.note-block').append(item);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the form as the context of the call and use it the find the div

```
$.ajax({
  url: 'ajax_post_com.php',
  type: 'POST',
  cache: false,
  data: $(this).serialize(),           //$(this) = a form
  beforeSend: function(){
      submit.val('Submitting...').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
  },
  context: this,
  success: function(data){
    var item = $(data).hide().fadeIn(800);
    $(this).parent().nextAll('.note-block:first').append(item); 
    //GOAL: append(item) onto the .note-block after only (this) form
  },
```